# How to give one radius corners to an imageview at runtime in android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am interested in giving a radius to only one corner of an imageview. I am using the following code to give round corners to imageview, but it works on all four corners and I want only one corner to be rounded.

```
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final int color = 0xff424242;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
final float roundPx = pixels;

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
```

Comment: you need to use `Path#addRoundRect`

Comment: can u suggest some code please.?

Comment: yes, i suggest [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#addRoundRect(android.graphics.RectF,%20float[],%20android.graphics.Path.Direction))

Answer (score -1):

You may try the following:
1. Extend ImageView
2. Override onDraw method

a. Create a clip path object (Path class object clipPath)
   b. Define your clipping region ( clipPath.addArc)
   c. Set clip path to Canvas
   d. Invoke super.Ondraw(Canvas)

Comment: how will you know the bounds of the clip?

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784208/draw-rounded-edge-arc-in-android-with-embossed-effect) to get an idea on clipping

Comment: your link has nothing to do with cliping, and yes i know how to use Canvas clipping, i was asking how do you know the area to clip inside your custom ImageView?

Comment: I was thinking  to define the complete path using arc and rectangle.